# Invalid x509 certificate for kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying reach my k8s master from my workstation. I can access the master from the LAN fine but not from my workstation. The error message is:

```
% kubectl --context=employee-context get pods
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.161.233.80, not 114.215.201.87
```

How can I do to add 114.215.201.87 to the certificate? Do I need to remove my old cluster ca.crt, recreate it, restart whole cluster and then resign client certificate? I have deployed my cluster with kubeadm and I am not sure how to do these steps manually.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One option is to tell `kubectl` that you don't want the certificate to be validated. Obviously this brings up security issues but I guess you are only testing so here you go:

```
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify --context=employee-context get pods
```

The better option is to fix the certificate. Easiest if you reinitialize the cluster by running `kubeadm reset` on all nodes including the master and then do

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=114.215.201.87
```

It's also possible to fix that certificate without wiping everything, but that's a bit more tricky. Execute something like this on the master as root:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm init phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=10.161.233.80,114.215.201.87
docker rm `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: I think this is not a legit answer anymore because this `alpha` subcommand is not available [anymore](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-alpha/#cmd-certs-renew).

Comment: For kubeadm 1.15, just run command `kubeadm alpha certs renew all`

Comment: because kubeadm `alpha` subcommand is not available anymore, you can replace it with the following command

`kubeadm init phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=10.161.233.80,114.215.201.87`

Answer (score 23):

This command for new kubernetes >=1.8:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm alpha phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=10.161.233.80,114.215.201.87
docker rm -f `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Also whould be better to add dns name into `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans` for avoid issues like this in next time.

Comment: You are a god!!

Comment: I'm getting `Error: unknown flag: --apiserver-advertise-address`. I think this alpha subcommand has changed a lot since then.

Comment: Thank you. For anyone having problems. Alpha is just the command for any experimental commands. When they are no longer experimental they get graduated and removed from `alpha`. `kubeadm init phase certs all` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 20):

For kubeadm v1.13.3

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm init phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=114.215.201.87
docker rm -f `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: works also nicely with v1.14.3. One thing I might add: Looks like private IPs are automatically added to `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans`, so you'll only have to add additional public IPs there

Comment: Works also nicely with v1.17.2. I needed --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee.

Answer (score 5):

If you used kubespray to provision your cluster then you need to add a 'floating ip' (in your case its '114.215.201.87').  This variable is called `supplementary_addresses_in_ssl_keys` in the `group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml` file.  After updating it, just re-run your `ansible-playbook -b -v -i inventory/<WHATEVER-YOU-NAMED-IT>/hosts.ini cluster.yml`.

*NOTE: you still have to remove all the apiserver certs (`rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*`) from each of your master nodes prior to running!*

Answer (score 4):

Issue cause:
Your configs at $HOME/.kube/ are present with your old IP address.

Try running,

```
rm $HOME/.kube/* -rf
cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Comment: This has nothing to do about .kube directory. It's possible that the IP does not match, but it doesn't mean we need to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

For Kubernetes 1.12.2/CentOS 7.4 the sequence is as follows:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm alpha phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=51.158.75.136
docker rm -f `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
kubeadm init phase certs all
```

Answer (score 0):

For me when I was trying to accessing via root (after sudo -i) I got the error.
I excited and with normal user it was working.

Answer (score -1):

For me the following helped:

1. `rm -rf ~/.minikube`
2. `minikube delete`
3. `minikube start`

Probably items no 2 and 3 would have been sufficient