# Configure AWS publicIP for a Master in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I did create a Master Cluster with the following command:

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr $CALICO_NETWORK`

Now it is listening in the internal IP 10.3.8.23:6443, which is ok because I want that the master uses the internal IP to communicate with Nodes.

Now I want to access the cluster using the public IP and I get the following error:

**http: proxy error: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.3.8.23, not for 18.230.*.*.**

How can I generate an additional certificate for the publicIP?

I need to use the public IP in order to access the dashboard using the browser.

I install it using: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to recreate your cluster you can also do what's described here: [Invalid x509 certificate for kubernetes master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master)

For K8s 1.7 and earlier:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm alpha phase certs selfsign \
  --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 \
  --cert-altnames=10.96.0.1 \
  --cert-altnames=10.3.8.23 \
  --cert-altnames=18.230.x.x  # <== Public IP
docker rm `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

For K8s 1.8 an newer:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm alpha phase certs all \
  --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 \
  --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=10.96.0.1,10.3.8.23,18.230.x.x # <== Public IP
docker rm -f `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

And you can also add DNS name with the `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access to your cluster using public IP, you can pass the IP with `kubeadm init` command. Like:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=private-ip,public-ip \
  --pod-network-cidr $CALICO_NETWORK \
  --apiserver-advertise-address=private-ip
```

Comment: If I do that this will restart my cluster and disconnect all nodes, is there a way to do that without reset the master?