# After building a single node Kubernetes cluster with `conjure-up` how can I access it using a public ip address?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I pay for a large(ish) server from Hetzner, and I wanted to get more things running on it. As I have been working with Kubernetes a lot over the past year or so I looked into installing a Kubernetes cluster on a single machine.

I found a way to do this with Ubuntu and that was to use `conjure-up`. This has worked well and when I am SSH'ed into the machine I am able to run `kubectl` commands and see the state of the cluster.

What I am not able to work out, and I am sure it is something simple that I missed, is how to make the API accessible over the public IP address and then eventually Ingress services.

I can see the internal services using `kubectl cluster-info`:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443
Heapster is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
CoreDNS is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
Grafana is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy        InfluxDB is running at https://10.106.77.143:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb:http/proxy
```

(IP addresses have been changed)

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://10.106.77.143:6443 is this a public IP?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but these addresses are in the private IP range.

Comment: Did you check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895437/is-it-possible-to-access-the-kubernetes-api-via-https-ingress