# Expose kubernetes api within ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-apiserver

So I exposed my kubernetes api through service using the following command.

```
kubectl -n kube-system expose pod kube-apiserver-master-node --name=apiserver --port 6443
```

When I describe the service I get this

```
Name:              apiserver
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            component=kube-apiserver
                   tier=control-plane
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          component=kube-apiserver,tier=control-plane
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.105.200.112
IPs:               10.105.200.112
Port:              <unset>  6443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.0.130:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Which seems to indicate that the service is running ok.
Then I ran this yml to add my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - k8s.domain.com
    secretName: domain-tls
  rules:
  - host: "k8s.domain.com"
    http:
      paths:
  - pathType: Prefix
    path: "/"
    backend:
      service:
        name: apiserver
        port:
          number: 6443
```

But when I try to browse the k8s.domain.com it doesn't work it give me a bad request (400). I also tried with port 80 on the ingress config but it doesn't work either it gives me a 503. I think I'm missing something. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895437/is-it-possible-to-access-the-kubernetes-api-via-https-ingress) question but it doesn't talk about how to expose the service through ingress.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: It’s bare metal. it works for other things on my domain. Just not the api

Comment: Could you please answer for all questions above? It will be helpful to reproduce your issue. Could you also attach your logs?