# Using kubeadm why would you want to manually generate certs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.inkubate.io/install-and-configure-a-multi-master-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm/).

1. What would be the advantage of generating the certs yourself instead of depending on kubeadm?
2. if you create the certs yourself, does the auto-rotation happens after setting up the cluster from kubeadm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No major advantage. kubeadm does the same: generate self-signed certs. The only mini advantage is that you could add some custom values in the [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request), such as a City, Organization, etc.
2. Not really.

   - There's a [kubelet certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/#enabling-client-certificate-rotation) rotation flag `--rotate-certificates` that needs to be enabled.
   - There's also the certificate rotation from the masters and `kubeadm` can help with that with these [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master?answertab=votes#tab-top):

     ```
     mkdir /etc/kubernetes/pkibak
     mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/* /etc/kubernetes/pkibak
     rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/*
     kubeadm init phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x
     systemctl restart docker
     ```

If you'd like to regenerate the `admin.conf` file, you can also use `kubeadm`:

```
$ kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin \
  --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki \
  --kubeconfig-dir /tmp/.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rico - always can depend on you sir!  Your second part of the answer - regenerating certs for Masters - "kubeadm alpha .. --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=x.x.x.x"  This would add extra valid IP and/or domain name?

Comment: You're welcome! you can add both an IP and domain name.

Comment: Sorry another question - if you use kubeadm alpha phase certs all -- does it also take care of the kubelet certificate as well?

Comment: Not really. Take a look at the output of `kubeadm alpha phase certs -h`

Comment: I used the command to generate the new certs and it worked -- but now none of the kubectl commands work because it is saying it does not trust the new cert -- not sure what further changes I need to make.

Comment: Hmm, did it generate a new `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`? if yes then you can copy that one to `~/.kube/config`. If not you'll have to populate your `client-certfificate-data` and `client-key-data` again in your `~/.kube/config`

Comment: It did not generate a new admin.conf -- I was trying to look for how to populate client-certificate-data and client-key-data without any luck.  I also tried looking in the pki files under /etc/kubernetes but none of had the certificate data.  Any pointers on how to get that info?  Thank you!

Comment: Added it to the answer `kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki --kubeconfig-dir /tmp/.`

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the info!

Comment: What if I just want K8S to use the root cert I created manually and generate cert chains from there? Can I just clear the existing cert dir, copy my root cert into pki as `ca.crt` and `ca.key` and let it generate the rest?

Answer (score 3):

I am creating all the certs by myself, the reason behind that is

1. The kubernetes cluster we use might not be updated every year, so we need certificates with longer expiry. Our applications doesn't support random docker restart and we are not accepting the kubeadm phase command to regenerate the certificates and restart the docker. Hence we created all the certificates with 5 years of expiry and provided it to kubeadm and it is working fine. Now, we don't have to worry about our certificate expiry every year.
2. No kubeadm doesn't provide the auto rotate facility of certificates, this is the reason we needed longer expiry of certificates in the first place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide the steps on how you generated the certificates?