# Is phase kubeconfig required after phase certs in kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've recently upgraded with kubeadm, which I expect to rotate all certificates, and for good measure, I also ran `kubeadm init phase certs all`, but I'm not sure what steps are required to verify that the certs are all properly in place and not about to expire.

I've seen a [SO answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334732/238322) `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all` is required in addition, but cannot find in the [kubernetes kubeadm documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/) telling me that it needs to be used in conjunction with phase certs.

What do I need to do to make sure that the cluster will not encounter expired certificates?

I've tried verifying by connecting to the secure local port: `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect localhost:10250 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep Not`, which gives me expirations next month.

While `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -noout -text` and `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt -noout -text` yield dates over a year in advance.

These conflicting dates certainly have me concerned that I will find myself like many others with expired certificates. How do I get in front of that?

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence `kubeadm init phase certs all` regenerates all your certificates including your `ca.crt` (Certificate Authority), and Kubernetes components use certificate-based authentication to connect to the kube-apiserver (kubelet, kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager) so you will also have to regenerate pretty much all of those configs by running `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all`

Keep in mind that you will have to regenerate the `kubelet.conf` on all your nodes since it also needs to be updated to connect to the kube-apiserver with the new `ca.crt`. Also, make sure you [add all your hostnames/IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074575/2989261) that your kube-apiserver is going to serve on to the `kubeadm init phase certs all` command (`--apiserver-cert-extra-sans`)

Most likely you are not seeing the updated certs when connecting through `openssl` is because you haven't restarted the Kubernetes components and in particular the kube-apiserver.  So you will have to start your kube-apiserver, kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager, etc (or kube-apiservers, kube-schedulers, etc if you are running a multi-master control plane) You will also have to restart your kubelets on all your nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of what is going on, though after deleting all .conf and files in pki, `phase certs` and `phase kubeconfig` plus a reboot of the server did not change the `openssl` certificate expiry indication.

Comment: Did you reboot all your k8s masters?

Comment: yes. It's a single master that has the taint removed, no worker nodes.

Comment: It may be configured to get the certificates from another place. Are your configs under `/etc/kubernetes/...`?

Comment: Yes, our configs are under `/etc/kubernetes`. I've verified by looking at the systemd kubelet service.

Comment: That's super weird. Unless your certs are embedded in the container of the given k8s component.  For example, in the kube-apiserver container.

Answer (score 0):

A month later, I've learned a little more and wanted to update this question for those who follow behind me.

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/15292) on Kubernetes requesting more information on how the kubeadm upgrade process automatically updates certificates. The documentation on Kubernetes says:

> Note: kubelet.conf is not included in the list above because kubeadm configures kubelet for automatic certificate renewal.

After upgrading, I did not see an automatic cert renewal for the kubelet. I was then informed that:

> the decision on when to rotate the certificate is non-deterministic and it may happen 70 - 90% of the total lifespan of the certificate to prevent overlap on node cert rotations.

They also provided the following process, which resolved my last outstanding certificate rotation:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/kubelet/pki /var/lib/kubelet/pki-backup
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
# the pki folder should be re-created.
```