# Kubelet - x509: certificate is valid for 10.233.0.1 not for <IP>

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubelet

I've installed my kubernetes cluster (two nodes) with [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray). Now I have added an third node. And I get the error from kubelet server on the new node:

> Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://94.130.25.248:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate is valid for 10.233.0.1, 94.130.25.247, 94.130.25.247, 10.233.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 94.130.25.247, 144.76.14.131, not 94.130.25.248

The IP 94.130.25.248 is the ip of new node.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master), where was wrote about recreating the apicert. But the new version of kubeadm (v1.13.1) don't have this option.

Also I've try to renew the certificates with command:

```
kubeadm alpha certs renew all --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml
```

This command regenerate the certificates, but with the same ips and dns.

My kubeadmin-config.yml (certSANs):

```
  certSANs:
  - kubernetes
  - kubernetes.default
  - kubernetes.default.svc
  - kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
  - 10.233.0.1
  - localhost
  - 127.0.0.1
  - heku1
  - heku4
  - heku2
  - 94.130.24.247
  - 144.76.14.131
  - 94.130.24.248
```

Can someone tell me how can I added the ip to apicert?

Answer (score 3):

hm...
I've removed the apiserver.* and apiserver-kubelet-client.* and recreated this with command:

```
kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config=/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml
kubeadm init phase certs apiserver-kubelet-client --config=/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml
systemctl stop kubelet
delete the docker container with kubelet
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: what do you mean by "delete the docker container with kubelet"?