# How to configure kubernetes so that I could issue commands against the master machine from my laptop?

Tags: security, kubernetes, x509, kubeadm

I'm trying to setup a cluster of one machine for now. I know that I can get the API server running and listening to some ports.

I am looking to issue commands against the master machine from my laptop.

`KUBECONFIG=/home/slackware/kubeconfig_of_master kubectl get nodes` should send a request to the master machine, hit the API server, and get a response of the running nodes.

However, I am hitting issues with permissions. One is similar to `x509: certificate is valid for 10.61.164.153, not 10.0.0.1`. Another is a 403 if I hit the `kubectl proxy --port=8080` that is running on the master machine.

I think two solutions are possible, with a preferable one (B):

A. Add my laptop's ip address to the list of accepted ip addresses that API server or certificates or certificate agents holds. How would I do that? Is that something I can set in `kubeadm init`?

B. Add `127.0.0.1` to the list of accepted ip addresses that API server or certificates or certificate agents holds. How would I do that? Is that something I can set in `kubeadm init`?

I think B would be better, because I could create an ssh tunnel from my laptop to the remote machine and allow my teammates (if I ever have any) to do similarly.

Thank you,

Slackware

Comment: are you doing `kubectl --kubeconfig KUBECONFIG get nodes`?

Comment: Upon any request, the API server sends its certificate and kubectl verifies it. Your first error message might mean that the API sever's certificate is valid for IP address 10.61.164.153, but the API server is actually running on IP address 10.0.0.1, so kubectl fails to verify this certificate.

Comment: You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master) a good explanation how to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans 10.0.0.1` to your `kubeadm init` command.

Refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options

You should also use a config file:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.16.2
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - 10.0.0.1
```

You can find all relevant info here: https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta2