# kubernetes authentication against the API server

Tags: authentication, ssl, curl, kubernetes, tls1.2

I have setup a `kubernetes` cluster from scratch. This just means I did not use services provided by others, but used the k8s installer it self. Before we used to have other clusters, but with providers and they give you `tls cert and key` for auth, etc. Now this cluster was setup by myself, I have access via `kubectl`:

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   21h
$
```

I also tried [this](https://shocksolution.com/2018/12/14/creating-kubernetes-secrets-using-tls-ssl-as-an-example/) and I can add a custom key, but then when I try to query via curl I get `pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope`.

I can not figure out where can I get the cert and key for a user to authenticate using the API for tls auth. I have tried to understand the official docs, but I have got nowhere. Can someone help me find where those files are or how to add or get certificates that i can use for the rest API?

**Edit1:** my .kube.config file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0t(...)=
    server: https://private_IP:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS(...)Qo=
    client-key-data: LS0(...)tCg==
```

It works from the localhost just normally.
In the other hand I noticed something. From the localhost I can access the cluster by generating the token using [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy) method.

Also notice that for now I do not mind about creating multiple roles for multiple users, etc. I just need access to the API from remote and can be using "default" authentication or roles.
Now when I try to do the same from remote I get the following:

1. I tried using that config to run `kubectl get all` from remote, it runs for a while and then ends in `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp`private_IP:6443`: i/o timeout.`
2. This happens because the config has `private_IP`, then I changed the IP to `Public_IP:6443` and now get the following : `Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for some_private_IP, My_private_IP, not Public_IP:6443`
3. Keep present that this is and `AWS ec2` instance with `elastic IP` (You can think of Elastic IP as just a public IP on a traditional setup, but this public ip is on your public router and then this router routes requests to your actual server on private network). For AWS fans like I said, I can not use the EKS service here.

So how do I get this to be able to use the Public IP?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.kube/config` file that was automatically generated? If yes, can you post it?

Comment: @weibeld, I added some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your main problem is the TLS server certificate validation.

One option is to tell kubectl to skip the validation of the server certificate:

```
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify ...
```

This has obviously the potential to be "insecure", but that depends on your use case

Another option is to recreate the cluster with the public IP address added to the server certificate. And it should also be possible to recreate only the certificate with `kubeadm` without recreating the cluster. Details about the latter two points can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360852/4747193).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This clarified a few things and it worked with the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify`, I also got to understand after some research how some of the components work. I will ultimately have to re-initialize the cluster.  or use the RBAC method suggested by @P Ekambaram.

Comment: It helps to not mix up things. Your description touches on different concepts: **(1)** API server TLS certificate verification (you have the CA certificate in the `clusters` section of your kubeconfig file), **(2)** authentication (you have the key and cert in the `users` section of your kubeconfig file), **(3)** authorisation (done with RBAC roles and role bindings). These are all entirely different concepts that happen at different times in the process and have their own techniques and issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup RBAC for the user. define roles and rolebinding. follow the link for reference -> https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

Comment: @P Ekambaram, thanks for your response. I am sure you are right, but I m probably to much of a newbie to understand these stuff. I added some further context that might be relevant.