# Kubernetes, Changing Server of Kops Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops

I have a kubernetes cluster setup on AWS using kops.

Right now, the server url is https://old-server-url.com.
This url is configured on Route53 pointing to public ip of master instance of cluster.

I want to change this to https://new-server-url.com.
I configured new url on Route53 same with master IP. But it just opens the kubernetes dashboard with new URL.
I can't access kubernetes server via kubectl with this url.

This is the error I get when changing the kubeconfig file with new url and running kubectl get pods command.

`"Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for internal.old-server-url.com, old-server-url.com, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not new-server-url.com"`

What configuration do I have to change so that only the server of kubernetes cluster is changed, and I can access it via kube config/ kubectl?

Update:
I can access my cluster after using --insecure-skip-tls-verify flag along the kubectl command. But this is insecure. I would like to know how can I change my certficates in a kops provisioned cluster with minimal effects for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just resolve the error:

```
"Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for internal.old-server-url.com, old-server-url.com, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not new-server-url.com"
```

You can use the --insecure-skip-tls-verify flag with kubectl command as explained here: [Invalid x509 certificate for kubernetes master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master)

This is not recommended for production environments.

Comment: Okay for dev environment but not recommended for production environment

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Kubectl uses a kubeconfig file.In that file you need to change the API server url from old url to the new url.

Edit:

The impact of changing the url is that you need to regenerate kube-apiserver certificate with the new url as 'host', otherwise kubectl will fail with a certificate validation error.

That happens because kubectl validates the server's certificate presented by kube-apiserver upon calling k8s API server

To regenerate the kube apiserver certs in the master nodes using kubeadm (kops internally uses kubeadm) you can run below command:

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
kubeadm init phase certs all --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=https://new-server-url.com
docker rm -f `docker ps -q -f 'name=k8s_kube-apiserver*'`
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Default SANs are kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, 10.96.0.1, 127.0.0.1

[Official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/#cmd-phase-certs)

Comment: I have done that, but after changing the kubeconfig file, I can't access the cluster.

Comment: what is the error? can you try running kubectl command with verbose set kubectl -v=8-get nodes

Comment: I can't run the command that you asked for. Can you please tell me exactly what command you want me to run in inverted commas.
Also, this is the error I get when changing the kubeconfig file with new url and running kubectl get pods command. "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for internal.old-server-url.com, old-server-url.com, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not new-server-url.com"

Comment: Sorry I made a typo can you try this "kubectl -v=8 get nodes"

Comment: I get the same error "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for internal.old-server-url.com, old-server-url.com, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not new-server-url.com".

I can access my cluster after using --insecure-skip-tls-verify flag along the kubectl command. But this is insecure. I would like to know how can I change my certficates in a kops provisioned cluster with minimal effects.

Comment: The command that you mentioned will just add new san for my domain. The certificate will still workk for my old domain. Is there a way so that the certificate doen't work fol old domain?

Comment: Ideally you will need to remove the existing certs and then run that command to generate new certs only with new SAN. Check updated answer

Comment: This needs to be done on the master, right?

Comment: Yes it needs to be done on master

Comment: Can yoy please tell me if this will have any down time on my cluster or any other side effects?