# connect to kubernetes cluster from local machine using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

I have installed a kubernetes cluster on EC2 instances on AWS.

1 master node and 2 worker nodes.

Everything works fine when I connect to the master node and issue commands using `kubectl`.

But I want to be able to issue `kubectl` commands from my local machine.
So I copied the contents of `.kube/config` file from master node to my local machine's `.kube/config`.

I have only changed the ip address of the **server** because the original file references to an internal ip. The file looks like this now :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUM1ekNDQWMrZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpNQjRYRFRJeE1URXhNVEUyTXpneE5Gb1hEVE14TVRFd09U4M0xTCkJ1THZGK1VMdHExOHovNG0yZkFEMlh4dmV3emx0cEovOUlFbQotLS0tLUVORCBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCg==
    server: https://35.166.48.257:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: 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
~
```

When I try to use a `kubectl` command from my local machine I get this error :

`Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 172.31.4.108, not 35.166.48.257`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bcs the kube-api server TLS cert is only valid for `10.96.0.1, 172.31.4.108` and not for `35.166.48.257`. There are several options, like to tell `kubectl` the skip TLS verfiy but i would not re-commend that. The best would be to re-generate the whole PKI on your Cluster.

Both ways are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360852/16776451)

Next time for a kubeadm Cluster you can use `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans=EXTERNAL_IP` at the cluster init to also add the external IP to the API Server TLS cert.